# How do I search for a specific XML value in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, blob

I'm trying to search for a given value in a XML binary type column in a SQL table (BLOB).

The table has +3000 records. I need to look for all the values that corresponds to a specific IP in /properties/ip/ from an XML that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
   <port>8000</port>
   <ip>12.345.67.80</ip>
</properties>
```

So far, I've been able to get *some* output but not what I needed (I could only run the query with the last WHERE claus, not without):

```
SELECT
    d.*,
    extractvalue(xmltype(d.CONFIGURATION,nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')),'properties/ip') as ip_lookup
FROM
    AZ.DEVICES d
WHERE
    NAME = 'Door-Entrance';
```

I am interesting in looking for all records with specific IP's, so something like this:

```
SELECT
    d.*,
    extractvalue(xmltype(d.CONFIGURATION,nls_charset_id('AL32UTF8')),'properties/ip') as ip_lookup
FROM
    AZ.DEVICES d
WHERE
    ip_lookup = '12.345.67.80';
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`XMLTABLE`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/XMLTABLE.html#GUID-C4A32C58-33E5-4CF1-A1FE-039550D3ECFA) which is recommended by Oracle rather than deprecated
functions `XMLSEQUENCE` or `EXTRACTVALUE` such as

```sql
WITH devices(configuration,name) AS
 (SELECT XMLType('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <properties>
           <port>8000</port>
           <ip>12.345.67.80</ip>
        </properties>'),
         'Door-Entrance'
    FROM dual)
SELECT ip
  FROM devices,
       XMLTABLE('/properties' PASSING devices.configuration COLUMNS "IP"
                VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'ip')
 WHERE name = 'Door-Entrance'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ffe024ec53b8ef9b2e7ec2d438b0de69)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Barbaros, thank you for the comment!

Would I be able to make something like "WHERE
    ip_lookup = '12.345.67.80'" in the end, to search for a specific IP?

Comment: You're welcome @jfe1337 . For the former deprecated case you can still use [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=eb94196bb9a0d5505efda7988e39b023) for backward compatibility as an option. For your current statement, there should raise an error due to the usage style of XmlType.

Comment: I have a big table with the XML type values in a BLOB column. Would I be able to parse all that with the WITH-clause, to find a specific IP? As far as I can see, with your query, this is only 1 one XML record. Thanks!

Comment: As already mentioned extractvalue is deprecated and shouldn't be preferred @jfe1337 , the query starting by a WITH clause is just an illustration, You can create a table with an XmlType column(namely `configuration`), which will check out the correctness of the value (whether there's a violation exists for an XML value) , as in this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=be79f5011cd96db5705a02cc99878111) rather than a BLOB.

Comment: Again, thanks for your kind response, Barbaros, I understand your point now. I am working with a database that has already been configured as a BLOB. Can I somehow select _each IP_ for each records in this DEVICES table? I'd like to fetch them all to be able to identify duplicates.

Comment: @jfe1337 Are you sure about the data type which's BLOB, presumably [CLOB](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2dd0920e8876acff835efce0fc4c335e) ?? (Be aware of `XmlType` conversion within the second case)

Comment: Yes. This is taken from DBvisualizer:
CONFIGURATION  BLOB
Allow NULL
BINARY, 356 Bytes, text/xml

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XMLTABLE` and either filter in the `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   AZ.devices d
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/properties'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(d.configuration,nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
         COLUMNS
           port NUMBER(5,0)  PATH './port',
           ip   VARCHAR2(15) PATH './ip'
       ) x
WHERE  x.ip = '12.345.67.80';
```

Or in the XPath:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   AZ.devices d
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/properties[ip="12.345.67.80"]'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(d.configuration,nls_charset_id('UTF8'))
         COLUMNS
           port NUMBER(5,0)  PATH './port',
           ip   VARCHAR2(15) PATH './ip'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE AZ.devices (
  name          VARCHAR2(30),
  configuration BLOB
);

INSERT INTO AZ.devices (name, configuration)
VALUES (
  'Door-Entrance',
  UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<properties>
   <port>8000</port>
   <ip>12.345.67.80</ip>
</properties>')
);
```

Both output:

> | NAME | CONFIGURATION | PORT | IP_LOOKUP |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Door-Entrance | <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <properties> <port>8000</port> <ip>12.345.67.80</ip> </properties> | 8000 | 12.345.67.80 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0b4e37807b0aacd47afa9c18c3187c2)*

Comment: Hi MT0, thank you for your kind response. I think this is a good method. However, I do have quite a few extra values in the CONFIGURATION blob which I didn't include in the question.

Comment: @jfe1337 Then add them to the `COLUMNS` clause if you want to output them or don't if you don't. I am failing to see what the issue is.

Comment: @jfe1337 You have not given any information that would allow me to answer your question as to how you would map them. I suggest that you just add appropriate lines to the `COLUMNS` clause of the `XMLTABLE` with the appropriate Xpath to the properties you want to map but beyond that I cannot be more specific as you have not shared any details.

Comment: If I get the error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 283", would this be due to incorrect mapping of datatypes?

Comment: @jfe1337 I have no idea, you have not shared your query or data.

Comment: I'd like to share it here, but StackOverflow seems to be built to support neither tables nor images:


/properties/
/properties/SwitchOnRelayNumber (6 characters, mixed)
/properties/<openMessage> (not a "folder")
/properties/<denyMessage> (not a "folder")
/properties/EmergencyLogEnabledProperty (folder w. booleans)
/properties/port 
/properties/ip
/10.152.20.31/<openUsingClipcardMessage> (not a "folder")
/properties/octocopler (folder w. booleans)

Comment: @jfe1337 Edit the [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d0b4e37807b0aacd47afa9c18c3187c2) linked in my answer to include your XML and query so that it replicates your error and then post a link to the updated fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. Here is an edited db<>fiddle with the XMLtype data col as well as the current query: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=c535edd806278583afb177c54099b2d8

Thanks!

Comment: I am assuming you mean something like [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3afa455b75204f29ffc7f02f5237182). I could not replicate your error though.